# Don't match regex when trailed by character

Tags: regex

Current regex: `[[\/\!]*?[^\[\]]*?]`

The goal it to successfully match `[size=16]` and `[/size]` in the following test case but not match `[abc]`.

```
[size=16]1234[/size]
[abc](htt)
```

Regex currently matches the 3rd test case; which is specific to always being followed by a parenthesis. So I was thinking about using the logic where if `group's next char == "(", do not match`

But- I don't really know how to write logic like that in regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) look before or ahead to see if there's a match and then proceed (or not) depending on whether there's a match.

A *negative* look*ahead* assertion looks like this:

```
(?!regex)
```

Stick it on the end, supplying it the parantheses and you're good to go:

```
[[\/\!]*?[^\[\]]*?](?!\()
```

https://regex101.com/r/2jEApI/1

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a "negative lookahead".

A "lookaround" is a group which gets matched, but not included in the result. They start with `(?` and end with `)`.

There are two types of lookaround, lookahead and lookbehind:

- A "lookbehind" looks backward and is indicated with a `<` immediately after the `?` (i.e. `?<`), but that's not what you're here for.
- A "lookahead" looks forward and is the default if there is no `<` after the `?`.

Both types can be either positive or negative:

- A positive lookaround requires the included group to be present to form a match and is indicated with an `=`.
- A negative lookaround requires that the included group is NOT present to form a match and is indicated with an  `!`.

After you have the basic structure for a positive or negative lookahead or lookbehind the contents in the middle is the normal regular expression syntax, the same as if it were any other group, so in your case you'll need an escaped left parenthesis `\(`.

Put it all together and you just need to tack this on the end of what you have: `(?!\()`